# How to initialize a variable of CameraPosition type using google Maps For Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio

I'm a beginner in Flutter and I'm using google maps flutter plugin for my App. I want to communicate to google my position.
When I'm running my app, I'm facing this issue

> LateInitializationError: Field 'googleMapAffichage' has not been initialized.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'reservation_place.dart';

class LocalisationMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocalisationMap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocalisationMap> createState() => LocalisationMapState();
}

class LocalisationMapState extends State<LocalisationMap> {
  //fonction initState qui va appeler getCurrentLocation lors de rechargement de la page
  @override
  // ignore: must_call_super
  void initState() {
    getCurrentLocation();
  }

  // variable qui communique a google map ma position
  late CameraPosition googleMapAffichage;
  //markeur qui indique notre position actuelle sur la map
  late Marker markerCurentPosition;

  //coordoner de ma position actuelle
  late double latitudeCurentPosition;
  late double longitudeCurentPosition;

  final numeroPlaceForm = TextEditingController();



  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    numeroPlaceForm.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // fonction qui m'envoie mes coordonners dans locationMessage sous format latitude longitude
  // et qui envoie a googleMapAffichage ma postion
  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    //fonction Geolocator qui me donne ma localisation
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    //coordoner obtenue grace a Geolocator
    double lat = position.latitude;
    double long = position.longitude;

    // locationMessage message comportant les coordonners a afficher
    // googleMapAffichage carte avec nos coordonners et un marqueur de notre position actuelle
    setState(() {
      googleMapAffichage = CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(lat, long),
        zoom: 14,
      );
      //coordoner de ma position actuelle
      latitudeCurentPosition = lat;
      longitudeCurentPosition = long;
      //markeur qui indique notre position actuelle sur la map
      markerCurentPosition = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("meMarker"),
        position: LatLng(lat, long),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'me'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
      );
    });
  }
```

That is my code snippet producing the error on the googleMapAffichage which represents Camera position. Flutter complaining the fact that is not initialized and I tried to solve it but so far I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

**Define** camera position variable like below,

```
CameraPosition? googleMapAffichage;
```

```html
getCurrentLoc()async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

    //coordoner obtenue grace a Geolocator
    double lat = position.latitude;
    double long = position.longitude;

    googleMapAffichage = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(lat, long),
      zoom: 14,
    );
  }
```